# Making a 3D, surfaced graph using gnuplot

Tags: c++, 3d, gnuplot

I am trying to make a 3D, surfaced graph using gnuplot (in C++). This is code I currently have.

```
  //gp << "set dgrid3d\n";
  //gp << "set samples 10,10\n";
  //gp << "set isosamples 10,10\n";
  //gp << "set contour\n";
  //gp << "set hidden3d\n";
  //gp << "set surface\n";
  //gp << "set pm3d\n";

  gp << "splot  't.dat' u 1:4:5 w linespoints pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \
  't.dat' u 2:4:5 w linespoints pointtype 9 pointsize 1.5, \
  't.dat' u 3:4:5 w linespoints pointtype 4 pointsize 1.5\n";
```

As you can see I have tried a number of commands (currently commented) to achieve the goal. I cannot seem to find a suitable combination of commands or a single command which gives me a 3D graph with a surface like which I seek.

This is 't.dat' - the data that I am attempting to plot:

```
#timeTaken1 timeTaken2 timeTaken3 D E
1.2342423 1.33 2.442 1 0 
1.234234 1.55 2.236 1 20 
2.56465 1.56 3.39 1 40 
2.464 1.234 3.224 1 60 
2.2747 1.768 3.552 1 80 
2.34774 1.876 3.574 1  100

3.34747 2.94 4.795 2 0 
3.34747 2.66 5.776 2 20 
3.3747 3.234 5.666 2 40 
3.787 3.66 6.503 2 60 
3.456 3.88 6.37 2 80 
4.345 3.345 5.853 2  100
```

Does someone know what needs to be done to make this work? Is there something wrong with the structure of the data? Is there some command I haven't seen?

Comment: What kind of surface are you looking for? What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I want a surface that covers an imaginary mesh laid over all the point on the graph. The problem I'm having is that none of these candidate commands does anything except 'set dgrid3d' which moulds the data points in an unacceptable way. Currently in general all I'm seeing is a 3D graph with some points on it.

Answer (score 1):

With `splot` you can only plot your data points (and connect them) as you can in 2D. To draw a surface, you have to find out an `f(x,y)` function and also `splot` it. Or you can manually interpolate a hundred or thousand of the surface coordinates into 't2.dat' and `splot 't2.dat' w l`.

Comment: "you can manually interpolate a hundred or thousand of the surface coordinates into 't2.dat' " what do you mean?

Comment: Depending your problem and your time, you can "guess" (calculate, estimate) the values of the surface on a dense x-y grid (eg. linear interpolation, spline, polynomial stb...) into a separate file; and then you can also `splot` this points with connecting them with lines (` w l`) to make the "illusion" of a continuous surface.